# What is the meaning of "adopter" in the phrase "adopter questions and suggestions"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> This database systems book has been successful through eight editions because the authors, editors, and the publisher paid attention to the impact of technology and to **adopter** questions and suggestions. We believe that this ninth edition successfully reflects the same attention to such stimuli. Furthermore this ninth edition marks the addition of a new
>   co-author, Steven Morris. Steven brings his wealth of knowledge, teaching experience, and expertise to this work.

I don't understand how the word **adopter** is used in this passage.

Comment: This strange choice of noun is made easier to understand by familiarity with the fixed term [**“early adopter”**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_adopter), used commonly in reference to people who incorporate a given technology into their lives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An **adopter** is "someone who adopts" - in this case, "adopts" means something along the lines of "starts to use, implements into his process". A company which "adopts a new technology" starts using this technology in its business process.

And "adopter questions" are "questions asked by adopters" - with "adopter" being an attributive noun (like in "chicken soup").

So the sentence could be rewritten as "[Authors] paid attention to the impact of technology and to questions and suggestions raised by people who used the system".

Answer (score 1):

In the field of academic book publishing, an "adopter" is a person who chooses to use a book in a course.  This forces (most of) the students in the class to purchase the book.  If a book goes through eight editions in 21 years, most college students will have to buy new books, because the old books will be out of date in less than three years.

At most colleges, the "adopters" are professors teaching the class, or committees in charge of academic departments.  At the elementary and high school level, adopters can be school principals, school district boards, or state-level school boards.